# Bash - checking variable value

Tags: bash

I am trying to check if the the variable $userSelection is not having value 1, 2 or 3, then I display error message. Tried the following and other combinations, but no luck.

```
if [ $userSelection -ne 1 || $userSelection -ne 2 ] || [ $userSelection -ne 2 || $userSelection -ne 3 ]
then 
    echo "Option selected not valid...please try again."
fi
```

Am getting error `[: missing`]'`.

Comment: You've got a rogue bracket in there `[ $userSelection -ne 2` Easy to miss with all those bars.

Comment: `[` is a command.  It has the odd behavior of requiring that its last argument be `]`.  You are trying to run the command `[ $userSelection -ne 1` and then (if it is successful) the command `$userSelection -ne 2`.  You must stop thinking of `[` as being a symbol in the grammar of the shell.  It is just a command.  This is often more clear if you spell it `test` (which is exactly the same as `[`, except that it does not require that its final argument be `]`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I really like your explanation. Great one!

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for highlighting that...classic mistake of overlooking

Comment: @JNevill Actually, that `[` is *necessary* to start a new command, because `[` doesn't support `||`. He's actually *missing* quite a few brackets.

Comment: @chepner That solves for OP's intentions, but not OP's original expectations of what they were writing. Your clarification is on point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your actual needs the right code should be the following:

```
if [ "$userSelection" -ne 1 ] && [ "$userSelection" -ne 2 ] && [ "$userSelection" -ne 3 ]
then 
    echo "Option selected not valid...please try again."
fi
```

From what you are saying the only right choices should be 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Missing brackets aside, the simplest way to make such a check is with a `case` statement instead:

```
case $userSelection in
   1|2|3) ;;
   *) echo "Option selected not valid...please try again." ;;
esac
```